# Attempting to Bundle a Require Command For a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, browserify

I want to create a chrome extension that will print out accessibility errors to the console using the axe-core library.  My plan was I originally thought I could do this with Browserify to bundle the axe-core library, but to simply add a content.js to the manifest, perform a require line in the contest.js, 'Browserify' content.js, and be ready to go. However, when I load up my extension and view the console, I see the Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined still in the console.

Here is content.js:

```
const axe = require('axe-core');
axe.run().then(results =>{console.log(results)});
```

Bundle.js is in place as one would expect. All the tutorials show browserify used to bundle node modules for scripts embedded in the html, can it not be used for content_scripts?  What is an alternative method for achieving this?

Comment: You must use a bundler (browserify, webpack, rollup, etc) because browsers don't have a `require`. There's no need for html, browserify works on js scripts directly. You need to use this result in manifest.json that you actually load in the browser i.e. not the original source content.js.